# Is it dangerous converting from float to BigDecimal then back?

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal, ieee-754

I'm in the process of making a program that generates test vectors to be used in a VHDL testbench. The testbench essentially tests a piece of hardware that acts as a single precision floating point adder, so the vectors are gonna conform to the IEEE 754 standard.

Anyway, my current plan for generation is to convert float values to `BigDecimal`, do the necessary arithmatic, then convert back to float. Is this dangerous? Will precision be lost resulting in a potentially inaccurate result in the test vector? I want to convert to `BigDecimal`, so I can avoid rounding issues.

So would this truncate the result?

```
BigDecimal repA = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(A));
BigDecimal repB = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(B));
BigDecimal repResult = repA.add(repB);
float result = repResult.floatValue();
```

Where A and B are some float.

Comment: You'll definitely loose some precision since a float cannot represent all possible fractional numbers.

Comment: Is there a way that I could accomplish this by not loosing any precision?

Comment: How accurate do you think you need it to be?

Comment: I guess that's pretty relative. I'd _like_ 100% accuracy if possible.

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible — some floating-point additions will inherently run into "rounding issues" (e.g, adding a very small number to a much larger one); part of testing the correctness of an adder will be to ensure that it rounds in a compliant fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to have accurate 32-bit float vectors within the expected limitations of a float, then I like your approach.  You're first converting from 32-bit float to an object with higher precision, performing several steps to your math, then converting back to 32-bit floating point.  In the end, your rounding errors would likely be lower than if you had performed the same series of steps natively in your 32-bit floats.

If your goal is to accurately simulate the expected results of a piece of hardware that is performing calculations natively using 32-bit floats, then you may run the risk of falsely reporting a test failure because your calculations are performed with more accuracy than the hardware being tested.

Comment: Based on your example, I don't see that you've avoided any rounding issues.  If you're just randomly generating vectors as floats, converting them to Strings, converting Strings to BigDecimal, adding, then converting back to floats, then you won't be any better off than just adding the floats.

Comment: See the piece of hardware that's modeled truncates the values as opposed to round. So part of my software is to generate random vectors along with edge cases. I can't have the result rounded or else the tests are gonna be useless since the hardware truncates.

Comment: Would I want do the calculation, then check if the fractional part of `BigDecimal` after the calculation fits within 23 bits? If it doesn't, truncate it and convert?